# Checking for diagonals in Game

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to recreate Connect Four, but I'm having some problems checking for a diagonal victory. I'll post some code down below but not all of it otherwise it would be tedious to read. I want to use the same `checkForVictory` function for all the three checks. Horizontally and vertically is already working, for diagonal I want to use an array with the combinations already, such array is stored in a var `diagonals`. I'm trying to loop twice over the array in order to get the numbers inside, but then I'm not sure how to proceed next, because my `checkForVictory` function is already looping once with the argument I'm gonna pass in, so it's kind of confusing. Every single slot has a class of `.slot`. The column in the html repeats for 7 times in total in order to have 42 slots. Hope somebody can help.

```js
if (checkForVictory(slotsInColumn)) {
            winner();
        } else {
            var slotsInRow = $(".row" + i);
            if (checkForVictory(slotsInRow)) {
                winner();
            } else {
                var slots = $(".slot");

                for (var j = 0; j < diagonals.length; j++) {
                    for (var x = 0; x < diagonals[j].length; x++) {
                        
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        switchPlayer();
    });
    
    
    
    
    function checkForVictory(slots) {
        var count = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < slots.length; i++) {
            if (slots.eq(i).hasClass(currentPlayer)) {
                count++;
                if (count == 4) {
                    return true;
                }
            } else {
                count = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

```css
.slot {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.hole {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border: 50px midnightblue solid;
    position: relative;
    left: -40px;
    top: -40px;
}

#board {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="board">
            
            <div class="column">
                <div class="slot row0">
                    <div class="hole"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="slot row1">
                    <div class="hole"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="slot row2">
                    <div class="hole"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="slot row3">
                    <div class="hole"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="slot row4">
                    <div class="hole"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="slot row5">
                    <div class="hole"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: It would help if you would include the HTML that has these `slot` and `row` classes.

Comment: I just edited the code including part of the HTML and CSS

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. The better practice is to actually keep the board's state in memory (as a 2D array of numbers or something similar), and have that determine what is displayed.

But you can also do it like you are doing: read the DOM to determine where the discs are.

Then you would need to loop over the 4 possible directions to determine where there is a 4-in-a-row. This takes quite some code, and therefore I prefer to do it with a regular expression. For this to work, you first read the DOM and convert it to a character string, where:

- "0" = empty slot
- "1" = yellow disc
- "2" = red disc
- ":" = column separator

So the string will have 42 characters + 6 separator characters = 48 characters.

- A vertical four-in-a-row will have four occurrences of "1" (or "2") next to each other.
- A horizontal four-in-a-row will have four occurrences of "1" (or "2"), where each pair is separated by 6 characters -- which can be anything (one will be a ":")
- A diagonal four-in-a-row will have such pairs separated by 7 characters (if slanted downward) or by 5 characters (if slanted upwards).

So here is a runnable snippet where you can click to get a disc in a column, and where a win is announced with a simple `alert`:

```js
let currentPlayer = "yellow";
let gameOver = false;

$(".column").click(function () {
    // Don't allow a move when game is already over
    if (gameOver) return;
    // Determine slot where disc should end up
    let slot = $(".slot:not(.yellow,.red)", this).last();
    if (slot.length === 0) return; // column is full
    // Place disc
    slot.addClass(currentPlayer);
    gameOver = checkForVictory();
    // Toggle player
    currentPlayer = currentPlayer == "yellow" ? "red" : "yellow";
    if (gameOver) alert("won");
});

function checkForVictory(slots) {
    // Convert game to a string of 48 characters
    let str = $.map($(".column"), col =>
        $.map($(col).children(), slot =>
            $(slot).hasClass("yellow") ? 1 : $(slot).hasClass("red") ? 2 : 0
        ).join("")
    ).join(":");
    // Return true if there is & four-in-a-row
    return /([12])(\1{3}|(.{5}\1){3}|(.{6}\1){3}|(.{7}\1){3})/.test(str);
}
```

```css
#board {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.column {
    display: inline-block;
}

.slot {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.hole {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    border: 20px midnightblue solid;
    position: relative;
    left: -17px;
    top: -17px;
}

.yellow {
    background: yellow;
}

.red {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="board">
    <div class="column"><div class="slot"><div class="hole"></div></div><div class="slot"><div class="hole"></div></div><div class="slot"><div class="hole"></div></div><div class="slot"><div class="hole"></div></div><div class="slot"><div class="hole"></div></div><div class="slot"><div class="hole"></div></div></div>
    <div class="column"><div class="slot"><div class="hole"></div></div><div class="slot"><div class="hole"></div></div><div class="slot"><div class="hole"></div></div><div class="slot"><div class="hole"></div></div><div class="slot"><div class="hole"></div></div><div class="slot"><div class="hole"></div></div></div>
    <div class="column"><div class="slot"><div class="hole"></div></div><div class="slot"><div class="hole"></div></div><div class="slot"><div class="hole"></div></div><div class="slot"><div class="hole"></div></div><div class="slot"><div class="hole"></div></div><div class="slot"><div class="hole"></div></div></div>
    <div class="column"><div class="slot"><div class="hole"></div></div><div class="slot"><div class="hole"></div></div><div class="slot"><div class="hole"></div></div><div class="slot"><div class="hole"></div></div><div class="slot"><div class="hole"></div></div><div class="slot"><div class="hole"></div></div></div>
    <div class="column"><div class="slot"><div class="hole"></div></div><div class="slot"><div class="hole"></div></div><div class="slot"><div class="hole"></div></div><div class="slot"><div class="hole"></div></div><div class="slot"><div class="hole"></div></div><div class="slot"><div class="hole"></div></div></div>
    <div class="column"><div class="slot"><div class="hole"></div></div><div class="slot"><div class="hole"></div></div><div class="slot"><div class="hole"></div></div><div class="slot"><div class="hole"></div></div><div class="slot"><div class="hole"></div></div><div class="slot"><div class="hole"></div></div></div>
    <div class="column"><div class="slot"><div class="hole"></div></div><div class="slot"><div class="hole"></div></div><div class="slot"><div class="hole"></div></div><div class="slot"><div class="hole"></div></div><div class="slot"><div class="hole"></div></div><div class="slot"><div class="hole"></div></div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! In the end I implemented something like this: 
else {
            for (var x = 0; x < diagonals.length; x++) {
                var slots = $(".slot");
                var counter = 0;
                for (var y = 0; y < diagonals[x].length; y++) {
                    if (slots.eq(diagonals[x][y]).hasClass(currentPlayer)) {
                        counter++;
                        if (counter === 4) {
                            winner();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
But it's repetitive.

Comment: Yes, and you have to also account for the code to initialise `diagonals`... There is quite a lot more code involved that way.